# tools to reconstruct the transcriptional regulatory circuits?

Tags: transcription, gene-regulation, software, systems-biology

What are commonly used tools to reconstruct the transcriptional regulatory circuits that govern diverse cellular responses and what input data sets do they accept?

Answer (score 3):

Inferring transcriptional / regulatory networks from empirical data is an active area of research, and to my knowledge there aren't many mature tools for this type of analysis. I see mostly mathematicians, statisticians, and engineers working on this problem, probably because of the intense quantitative theory involved. Even if mature tools *do* exist, I doubt they're tailored for the typical biologist--more likely, they are geared toward scientists with a more quantitative background.

That being said, I am aware of 2 or 3 pieces of software that may provide a starting point for the curious or the adventurous: [AIRnet](http://dna.cs.byu.edu/airnet/) (described [here](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2164/11/S2/S6)), [iBioSim](http://www.async.ece.utah.edu/iBioSim/) (described by Barker's PhD thesis, currently the second hit on [this Google search](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=Learning+Genetic+Regulatory+Network+Connectivity+from+Time+Series+Data&oq=Learning+Genetic+Regulatory+Network+Connectivity+from+Time+Series+Data&aq=f&aqi=g-K1&aql=&gs_l=hp.3..0i30.166603.166603.4.167534.1.1.0.0.0.0.282.282.2-1.1.0...0.0.dr9esAhRzF8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=85a3745797f087a1&biw=1650&bih=914)), and maybe [Ingenuity Pathways Analysis](http://www.ingenuity.com/products/pathways_analysis.html) (which requires a paid license). The only one of these tools I've even tried to use is iBioSim, and at the time (2 or so years ago) it was a very kludgy process.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add [regulonDB](http://regulondb.ccg.unam.mx/) which is not as integrated, but has a tremendous map of the e coli regulome which would be useful for any bacterial model.

I agree with @DanielStandage that this is not a well understood and there don't even appear to be standard representations for this sort of data.

Comment: The [Systems Biology Markup Language (SBML)](http://sbml.org/Main_Page) is the closest thing to a standard representation out there, but it's been adopted about as widely as every other XML-based bioinformatics format I've encountered.